# Drupal 7 module - get all form submissions

Tags: drupal-7

How do you retrieve all form submissions (specific form ID) from the database for module development

looking to grab form subs and do some processing before offering parsed data for download

Answer (score 0):

This one got me thinking (and researching a bit..).. I don't think there's actually a way to get all form submissions for Form API. And come to think of that, it kinda makes sense, because forms API is just that, a Forms API that helps with all the process of generating forms, validating them and handling submissions.

You're still the one that has to define what happens to form submissions - which also means you can do different things such as changing settings, updating nodes, entities, .. So, when it comes to listing the submissions, it depends not on the form itself but where those form results were actually stored. If it's a node then you can get the results with node_load(). If it's an entity you can get it using entity_load() and so forth..

All that said, if you're actually referring to Entity Forms API, then you can get all form submissions using the entityform_get_submissions() function:

```
function entityform_get_submissions($type = NULL, $uid = NULL, $draft = 0, $limit = NULL)
```

Just use the type parameter to get all submissions, think you can safely ignore the other parameters to get what you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using **Webform** module, `webform_get_submissions` can retrieve all submission on given nid.

```
$submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid'=><NID>))
```